# Android SupportLib - FrameLayout in CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout consuming entire screen-height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-design

I am currently having an issue with a `FrameLayout` in a `CoordinatorLayout` from Android design-support library whereas I followed the instructions from this [post](http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/) while creating the tabs.

Basically most things work as expected, the container-fragments are inflated into the `FrameLayout` and theirs tab-fragments are correclty added to the `ViewPager` as tabs (need it this way because I have got numerous fragments which should reuse the layout).

The problem I am struggling with is that the `FrameLayout` (and as a result also the tab-fragments) consumes the entire screen-height so it overlaps the `Toolbar` and the `TabLayout`. In order to visualize the problem I have created the following image:

[image: Visualized issue]

**Base-Layout with `CoordinatorLayout`, `Toolbar`, and `TabLayout`:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Separate layout used by the fragments inflated into `container`:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

All fragments are inflated by my `BaseFragment`-class (on another post on SO calling `inflater.inflate(getLayoutRes(), null);` was the issue causing the same problem)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(getLayoutRes(), container, false);
}
```

If I replace the `CoordinatorLayout` with a normal `LinearLayout` the `FrameLayout` starts below the `AppBarLayout` as expected but as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) the `AppBarLayout` for most of it´s features requires to be a direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

I could just add a `marginTop` to the `FrameLayout` but I would like to know if there is any appropriate solution for this. Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Move your `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `FrameLayout` - that attribute needs to be on the direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: This solved the same problem I had, thank you, but I have no idea why. What does `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` do exactly..?

Comment: @MicroR - I'd suggest reading the Javadoc of [AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior[(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html) or looking at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java#1128) - it adds the required padding to not overlap the `AppBarLayout` as well as allow the `AppBarLayout` to respond to scrolling if put on a scrollable View (such as `NestedScrollView` or `RecyclerView`)

Comment: @ianhanniballake  i have used ur suggestion but issue is i m getting some extra space in between my tablayout and framelayout i have applied bk color to analyze the reason but no background color appears in UI

Comment: @Erum - without a separate question with your code, it is impossible to know what you're doing

Comment: for me it helped to replace <include layout="@layout/toolbar" /> with direct toolbar placement